# Testing if session was set to a particular value

Tags: django

So the only thing I can find is how to set a session during testing. What I want is to check if view set session to a particular value.

This is how I imagine this should be like:

```
c = Client()
response = c.post('/whatever/')
self.assertEqual('wanted value', response.session['my_value'])
```

So `cookie` is available, but not `session`. This cannot be this hard.

Answer (score 0):

The Client has a `session` attribute, as shown [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/#django.test.client.Client.session).

Comment: Only the problem is that it doesn't work. I guess it's related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550078/how-do-i-properly-unit-test-a-django-session Coming from Rails, this is pretty sad.